# Difference between python2 and 3 for numbers with leading zeroes.

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.x

In Python2.7 if I type,

```
0600
```

I get,

```
384
```

In python 3.4 if I type,

0600

I get,

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    0600
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, you have to use `oct(DEC)` or `0oOCT` to specify/convert to and from octal numbers.

```
>>> oct(384)
'0o600'
>>> 0o600
384
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `0` is no longer a valid literal prefix on its own, for clarity's sake.

```
3>> 0o600
384
```